# Using boost-di with configuration file and shared libraries

Tags: c++, boost, dll, dependency-injection

I am planning a c++ project using dependency injection via boost di. In my opinion I will need a mechanism for dynamically loading libraries too, to be able to realy benefit of dependency injection.

Therefore I consider using boost dll to use a platform independent shared library mechansim.

For dependency configuration I think about using INI-files via boost property tree.

Do you see any major drawback in this approach? 
Or is there another platform independent mechanism/library?

Thanks for your opinions
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mechanism to decide during runtime what implementation to use. But due to the compile time approach of Boost DI it seems by design not intended to use it with dynamic libraries.

For a pure compile time injection it looks very smart and nice to use. For my problem, it seems not the right solution.

Comment: Hello! Would you kindly tell what is your final solution to the problem? I am facing the same problem with DI and shared libraries. Right now I am looking at Boost.DI and Google Fruit. It seems like it should be possible to configure injection in runtime by using some kind of factory and dynamic binding mechanics.

Comment: @InnokentiyAlaytsev Finally we decided not to use Boost.DI. In fact, we where not using "real" DI for our project, but simply used self contained modules that we loaded according to a configuration during load time of the application.

Answer (score 2):

During C++ projects development, I had to find a C++ DI framework.

After some investigation and evaluations and based on our requirements (detailed below), we found out that [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic)  framework suits our needs.

Our criterions (*except the basic one that the framework shall recursively inject instances !!*) were:

1. **Non-intrusive** (do not require to dirty existing code with 'decorations' macros...) as [Google fruit](https://github.com/google/fruit) and or other libs require.
2. Support **singleton** instance
3. Support of **configurable** instantiation (using a lambda)
4. Support of container\injector **composition**
5. **Generic Shareable container**\injector in order to support modules (static or dynamic). BTW, I agree with

Boost-DI, as answered by Andreas, is not suitable because it is heavily templated and as answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56091707/boost-di-vs-google-fruit).
Boost-DI does not allow real composition of containers at run-time and even not at compile-time unless you share the header files with the root injector. It violates the 'privacy' of modules (as you need to publish them to be able to inject them).
Hypodermic allows to configure containers and create sub-containers. Container is agnostic to type (not template) therefore it is possible to share it at run-time.
BTW, this solves also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72875561/c-dependency-injection-with-dynamic-library-loading)